Contradiction (or mistake) in $\displaystyle \iint x^y ~ dx ~ dy$
I came across this double integral at an Instagram post and I tried to solve it. The integral in question is the following:
$$I = \iint x^y ~ dx ~ dy$$
So, I begun by calculating the inner integral first getting:
$$\int x^y ~ dx = \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + c_1$$
Then I have to integrate this with respect to $\displaystyle y$:
$$\int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + c_1 ~ dy = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + \int c_1 ~ dy = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + {c}_{1}y$$
I figured I'd solve the first integral with integration by parts using this formula:
$$\int u ~ dv = uv - \int v ~ du$$
$$u = {x}^{y+1}$$
$$du = {x}^{y+1} \ln(x) ~ dy$$
$$dv = \frac{1}{y+1} ~ dy$$
$$v = \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl)$$
Plugging all this back to the formula I get:
$$\int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy = {x}^{y+1} \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl) ~ - \int \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl) {x}^{y+1} \ln(x) ~ dy = {x}^{y+1} \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl) ~ - {x}^{y+1} \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl) ~ + c_2 = c_2$$
Therefore I get the answer to the original integral to be:
$$I = \iint x^y ~ dx ~ dy = {c}_{1}y + c_2$$
This did seem odd and I used Wolfram Alpha to check my answer. Acccording to Wolfram the correct answer is:
$$I = \iint x^y ~ dx ~ dy = \text{Ei}\bigl( (y+1) \ln(x) \bigl) ~ + {c}_{1}x + c_2$$
Ei is supposed to be the exponensial integral:
$$\text{Ei}(x) = - \int_{-x}^{\infty} \frac{{e}^{-t}}{t} ~ dt$$
I did some research on this and I figured out that Wolfram (and some other sites) solve this integral using u-substitution. So my question is, did I do something wrong in the calculation process or is integration by parts prohibited in this integral and if so why?. Also, I noticed that the first constant is multiplied with x instead of y even if the integral is with respect to y, which is weird.

There might be Multiple Issues , though the most obvious is this :
$$dv = \frac{1}{y+1} ~ dy$$
$$v = \ln \bigl( |x+1| \bigl)$$
It should be :
$$v = \ln \bigl( |y+1| \bigl)$$

Oh yeah I didn't even notice that. Thank you!

No worries ! When you handle that mistake & continue suitably , you will eventually get something like what Wolfram gave , though more work will be necessary.

You wrote :$\quad \int x^y ~ dx = \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + c_1\quad$ which isn't fully correct because $c_1$ isn't constant in general. To avoid ambiguity :
$$\int x^y ~ dx = \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + f(y)$$
Then you wrote : $\quad\int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + c_1 ~ dy = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + \int c_1 ~ dy = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + {c}_{1}y\quad$ which should be :
$$\int \left(\frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} + f(y)\right) ~ dy = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + \int f(y) ~ dy+\Phi(x) = \int \frac{{x}^{y+1}}{y+1} ~ dy + F(y)+\Phi(x)$$
The functions $f$, $F$ , $\Phi$ are arbitrary functions.

What exactly do these arbitrary functions represent? Are they the "constants of integration" (not really constants but functions of y and x)? And why did you write one for y and one for x when the outer integral has not been calculated?

$y$ acts as a parameter (i.e. an arbitrary constant wrt $x$) wen you integrate wrt $x$. Thus the constant of integration $c_1$ depends on the parameter $y$ : We write it $f(y)$ with arbitrary $f$. Also  $x$ acts as a parameter (i.e. an arbitrary constant wrt $y$) wen you integrate wrt $y$. Thus the constant of integration depends on the parameter $x$ : We write it $\Phi(x)$ with arbitrary $\Phi$. The arbitrary functions  can be determined if some valid boundary conditions are specified.

Oh I see. Thanks for the clarification.
